# How does AUC of decision tree being calculated?

Tags: machine-learning, decision-tree

Suppose I have a dataset which only has one continuous variable, and I try to use decision tree algorithm to build a model which classify the +ve and -ve label from the dataset. I run 10-fold cross-validation.

How does the AUC being calculated for the Decision Tree classifier? Will the algorithm check different threshold value of the classifier, and determine the AUC?

What about I have more than 2 continuous variable?

Thanks!

Comment: Belongs on stats.stackexchange.com.  Not programming related.

Answer (score 1):

Off topic, but hey:

AUC only makes sense for binary classification. The number of predictors does not matter.

Decision trees do not inherently have a 'threshold' but typically in a classification problem, the leaves contain a probability distribution over the 2 classes, and so does the tree's prediction. So you could conceive of picking the positive class only if its probability is >= p, not just >= 0.5. Then you could draw an AUC curve.

So it's a little unnatural to apply this to a decision tree but can be done.

Comment: can p be that threshold?

Comment: Yes that's what I mean!

Comment: Thanks! I got it now~